# Laravel API Response should not contain index

Tags: php, json, laravel

I creates an API in which I am accepting this as JSON:

```
{
  "productlist": [
      {"student_id": 216, "product_id": 4, "product_qty": 2},
      {"student_id": 216, "product_id": 6, "product_qty": 2}
  ]
}
```

I process this on server side like this:

```
$data = $request->json()->all();
$productlist = $data['productlist'];
$total_amount = 0;
foreach($productlist as &$pl){
    $pl['total_amount'] = $this->get_itemdetail($pl['product_id'])[0]->item_price * $pl['product_qty'];
    $pl['product_detail'] = $this->get_itemdetail($pl['product_id']);
    $total_amount+= $this->get_itemdetail($pl['product_id'])[0]->item_price * $pl['product_qty'];
}
//dd($productlist);
$productlist['cart_total'] = $total_amount;

return  response()->json(['data'=>$productlist, 'status'=> 200, 'message'=> 'Cart Processing Successfully']);
```

**Response From API**

```
{
"data": {
    "0": {
        "student_id": 216,
        "product_id": 4,
        "product_qty": 2,
        "total_amount": 100,
        "product_detail": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "item_name": "Chocolate",
                "description": "dairy milk chocolate",
                "item_price": "50",
                "total_stock": 160,
            }
        ]
    },
    "1": {
        "student_id": 216,
        "product_id": 6,
        "product_qty": 2,
        "total_amount": 46,
        "product_detail": [
            {
                "id": 6,
                "item_name": "Biscuit",
                "description": "Biscuit",
                "item_price": "23",
                "total_stock": 10,
            }
        ]
    },
    "cart_total": 146
},
"status": 200,
"message": "Cart Processing Successfully"
}
```

But I do not want to indexing in response. Should be like this:

**Desired Response**

```
{
"data": {
     {
        "student_id": 216,
        "product_id": 4,
        "product_qty": 2,
        "total_amount": 100,
        "product_detail": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "item_name": "Chocolate",
                "description": "dairy milk chocolate",
                "item_price": "50",
                "total_stock": 160,
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "student_id": 216,
        "product_id": 6,
        "product_qty": 2,
        "total_amount": 46,
        "product_detail": [
            {
                "id": 6,
                "item_name": "Biscuit",
                "description": "Biscuit",
                "item_price": "23",
                "total_stock": 10,
            }
        ]
    },
    "cart_total": 146
},
"status": 200,
"message": "Cart Processing Successfully"
}
```

**How can I get this desired response.?**

Comment: For some clarification, `data: { { ... } }`, as you say you're expecting, is not valid JSON. If you want multiple Objects nested under `"data": ...`, it needs to be an Array, so `"data: [{ ... }, {...}]`, but that doesn't work when you also have `"cart_total": 146`, which is why the 2 prior objects are `0: { ... }, 1: { ... }`, followed by `"cart_total: 146`. Maybe you're looking for something like `"data": { "students": [{ ... }, { ... }], "cart_total": 146 }`?

Comment: @TimLewis "data": { "students": [{ ... }, { ... }], "cart_total": 146 } yes  i wants like this. but it is more good if it looks like this "data": { [{ ... }, { ... }], "cart_total": 146 } means without students

Comment: Again, that's not valid. Objects in JSON need to have a key for each property, and `"data": { [{...}, {...}], "cart_total": 146 }` is missing an identifier before `[{ ... }, { ... }]`, which is why I suggested `"students: [ ... ]`  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Whyts.png (invalid) vs https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1rvO.png (valid)

Comment: You could also simply move `"cart_total": 146` _outside_ of `"data": ...` (like you're doing with `status` and `message`), but ultimately, you're in control of this data structure 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved the desired output by following @ArtisticPhoenix answer and @TimLewis Comment.

First I used `array_values` like this

```
return  response()->json(['data'=>array_values($productlist), 'status'=> 200, 'message'=> 'Cart Processing Successfully']);
```

And I moved the `"cart_total": 146` outside of `"data": ...`  (like I am doing with status and message)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
return  response()->json(['data'=>array_values($productlist), 'status'=> 200, 'message'=> 'Cart Processing Successfully']);
```

Or you may have to do it just before the foreach

```
$productlist = array_values($data['productlist']);
```

Basically you have string keys in the product list array, so it's treating it like an Object when doing the JSON encode, an easy way to remove the keys is with `array_values`.

I think there is a JSON flag as well (you can use when encoding), but I would have to look that up, because I forget if that is encoding or decoding....

The proper JSON response is this

```
"data": [{...},{...}]
```

Where data is an array and not an Object.  It's an Array of Objects, basically.  Objects will have keys like `{"key" : "value"}` in PHP this is equivalent, to either an associative array ( an array with string keys ) or the public properties of an object.  To get the Array in JSON `[]` without keys, you need the equivalent in PHP which is a numerically indexed array.

Comment: it is ok now but it removes cart_total and just  showing 146

Comment: do it prior to the foreach `$productlist = array_values($data['productlist']);`

Comment: *"I think there is a JSON flag [...] I forget if that is encoding or decoding"* - I think you're thinking of when decoding. The encoding part is done automatically in Laravel via `response()->json()`, but great points on Object vs Array in Javascript/JSON vs PHP's Indexed/Associative arrays; this catches a lot of people when using those 2 

Comment: $productlist = array_values($data['productlist']); by doing this indexing is again added same response.

Answer (score 0):

You should build your $productlist array as an associative array, not an indexed one.
Try this: Create an empty array to store the modified product list (before foreach loop).

```
$updatedProductList = [];
```

inside the foreach loop after the $total_amount, Remove the numerical index by assigning each product to the updatedProductList array directly.

```
$updatedProductList[] = $pl;
```

and return your response like this

```
$productListWithoutIndexes = array_values($updatedProductList);
$productListWithoutIndexes['cart_total'] = $total_amount;
return response()->json(['data' => $productListWithoutIndexes, 'status' => 200, 'message' => 'Cart Processing Successfully']);
```

Comment: Itried this but it gives me Same Response

Answer (score 0):

this one `$productlist = colelct($data['productlist'])->values();`

OR `$productlist = array_values($data['productlist'] ?? []);`

**->values()** - use whenever your indexes are offset in the list